# Transforming HTML like XDT Transformation

Tags: html, transformation, xdt-transform, xdt

to transform html files I began to use XDT Transformations. All worked fine until my HTML wasn't xhtml conform. But I also want to transform "normal" HTML5, which does not have to be XHTML conform.
Do you know of a toolset or anything else that has similar functionality like the XDT Transformations, but does work with non-xml-conform HTML?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do what you wanted? I ask because I'm also hoping to be able to transform HTML with XDT Transformations.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the only non-conforming part of my html was the javascript. This can be solved by placing this within your script:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
    put your javascript in here
//]]>
</script>
```

My XDT works fine once I do that.

Comment: This will only safe for characters in the script tag, not fix problems with unclosed tags that are commen to html5.